# jQuery Ajax sending data to php with one button click but two different actions

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to achieve is a user to follow another user without having to refresh the page. So far I've played around and had no problem inserting and deleting the rows in mysql table, but now when I'm trying with AJAX I can't get it to work.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#followbutton").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var theuserid = $('#theuserid').val();
var thefollower = $('#thefollower').val();

$.ajax({
url: 'includes/followuser.inc.php',
type: 'post',
data: {'theuserid': theuserid, 'thefollower': thefollower, 'submitFollow': true},
success: function(response){
$('#followmessage').html(response);   
$("#followmessage").show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
$('#followbutton').hide();
$('#unfollowbutton').show();

// $("#unfollowbutton").hover(function(){
// $(this).text("Unfollow");
// }, function(){
// $(this).text("Unfollow");
// });
    
}
});
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#unfollowbutton").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var theuserid = $('#theuserid').val();
var thefollower = $('#thefollower').val();

$.ajax({
url: 'includes/followuser.inc.php',
type: 'post',
data: {'theuserid': theuserid, 'thefollower': thefollower, 'submitUnfollow': true},
success: function(response){
$('#followmessage').html(response);   
$("#followmessage").show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
$('#unfollowbutton').hide();
$('#followbutton').show();

//I want the button to change its text to Following and when hovering it should say unfollow if user is followed

}
});
});
});
```

followuser.inc.php

```
<?php
require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
require_once 'functions.inc.php';
if (isset($_POST["submitFollow"])){
$userthatisfollowed = $_POST["thefollower"];
$theuserid = $_POST["theuserid"];

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO userfollow (thefollower, theuserid, followstatus) VALUES (?,?,?)');
$followstatus = 1;
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $userthatisfollowed, $theuserid, $followstatus);
$stmt->execute();
echo $response = "<span>Followed!</span>";
$stmt->close();

} else if(isset($_POST["submitUnfollow"])){
$userthatisfollowed = $_POST["thefollower"];
$theuserid = $_POST["theuserid"];
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE userfollow FROM userfollow WHERE thefollower = ? AND theuserid = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $userthatisfollowed, $theuserid);
$stmt->execute();
echo $response = "<span>Unfollowed!</span>";
$stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "DID NOT WORK";
}
```

profile.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && $_SESSION["userid"] != $userthatisfollowed) {
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("includes/followuser.inc.php");?>" id="followform" method="post">
<?php

if ($resulted->num_rows > 0){
$subscribe_status = "Unfollow";
$subscribe_text = "Following";

} else {
$subscribe_status = "Follow";
$subscribe_text = "Follow";
}


echo "<button name='submit".$subscribe_status."' id ='unfollowbutton' type='submit' style='display:none'>";
echo "<span>".$subscribe_text."</span>";
echo "</button>";

echo "<button name='submit".$subscribe_status."' id ='followbutton' type='submit'>";
echo "<span>".$subscribe_text."</span>";
echo "</button>";


// echo "<button name='submit".$subscribe_status."' id ='notificationbell' type='submit' style='display:none'>";
// echo "<i class='fa fa-bell'></i>";
// echo "</button>";

echo "<div id='followmessage'></div>";
?>
<input type="hidden" name="theuserid" id="theuserid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["userid"] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="thefollower" id="thefollower" value="<?php echo $userthatisfollowed; ?>">
</form>
<?php
}
```

What's worth noting is that I'm getting the response `DID NOT WORK` which tells me that `if(isset($_POST["submitUnfollow"]))` is not set. However, If I try with `if(isset($_POST["theuserid"]) && (isset($_POST["thefollower"]))` then it actually works for the insert query but not for the delete query.

Comment: You're not sending `submitFollow` in the `data:` argument, so `if (isset($_POST['submitFollow']))` won't succeed.

Comment: @Barmar How would I do it considering that there is a clickevent on that exact button? you mean like this var thebutton = $('#followbutton').val(); and have that in the data:argument as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `submitFollow` parameter in the `data:` object. Instead, you have `followbutton: true`, which isn't used by the PHP code. So change that to:

```
data: {'theuserid': theuserid, 'thefollower': thefollower, 'submitFolow': 'true'},
```

And for the unfollow button, use `submitUnfollow` instead.

Comment: thank you, did not know you could do it that way.

Comment: It is currently working, however I still need to refresh the page in order for the button texts to change. If the user Follows another user, the button/click event should be changed to Unfollow. This only happens whenever I refresh the page

Comment: Create both a follow button and unfollow button. When the user clicks on button, hide that button and show the other. I don't see any way for the user to choose who they're following, since you have that in a hidden input, it's not something they select.

Comment: and both of the buttons should be outside of the if statement that is checking the subscribe status? @Barmar

Comment: Yes, they're just in the static HTML.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that everytime I refresh the page the value of subscribe_status becomes Follow so the user can be followed again even tho there already is a record in the table, which is wrong. However, with ajax it works as intended

Comment: And if i put in the buttons inside of the if statements I cannot use for example $('#unfollowbutton').hide();
$('#followbutton').show();

Comment: I've updated the post so you can see the code jquery and html

Comment: Don't put the buttons inside the `if`. The `if` statement should just specify whether the button is hidden or shown.

Comment: This should be a new question, I already answered the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250485/discussion-between-votum-and-barmar).